# expected unqualified-id before int

Tags: c++

I got this error "expected unqualified-id before int" in c++ when I was trying to compile it.

```
void yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears), int yearlyAmount, double interestRate)
{
    int age = startingAge;
    int lastAge = startingAge + numOfYears;
    double cash = yearlyAmount;
    cout << "Age | Yearly Plan" << endl;
    cout << "----+----------------" << endl;
    while (age <= lastAge)
    {
        cout.width(3);
        cout << age << " | ";
        cout.width(15);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout << cash << endl;
        if (age != lastAge)
            cash = cash + cash*interestRate / 100.0;
        age++;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I tried to find what went wrong but couldn't.

Comment: Error messages include **line numbers**, and those should be included as part of the error message. In this case it's easy without it, but in general, if people have to guess where the error occurred, they won't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

```
void yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears), int yearlyAmount, double interestRate)
// --------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Holy sh*t. I was so blind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

```
void yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears), int yearlyAmount, double interestRate)
```

The `)` in the middle of this line could be an obvious pointer to a problem before *'an int'*.